# Edit of useless tag for question rejected by original questioner

Tags: discussion

recently I tried to edit the tags for this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041446/how-to-generate-and-insert-millions-of-random-numbers-and-save-in-a-database-in).

My concern was to remove the tag 'eloquent' as it has nothing to do with the question. However this got rejected by the person who asked the orginal question. I'm completely sure that this tag is useless for this question. Why could the questioner reject that edit by his own? Is it that I have less reputation? I have seen on StackOverflow that edits have to be approved or rejected by different members. Why not in this case ?

Comment: The owner of the post has the last word regarding edits on their post. Regardless of wether they're right or wrong.

Comment: @Eric D ... unless you have enough reputation...

Comment: Rep doesn't change anything in this case. The owner of a post can roll-back any edit, regardless of their rep. That the edit was suggested by a <2K user or directly submitted by a >2K user doesn't change anything either. I guess the only exception is if a *moderator* made an edit then locked/protected the post.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild _"unless you have enough reputation"_ Nope, they can always rollback. Now if they're refusing/rolling back great edits and making their post worse because of it, that is an issue and can usually be brought up to the mods. In this case, it's one tag... Not worth too much fuss over. To answer your questions, post owners can always reject suggested edits to their post or rollback their post, regardless of their reputation. They have binding votes on the suggested edits, as well. That's why it was so easily rejected.

Comment: @Kendra thanks for the explanation... But then somewone who askes a question has really great power of using tags. He might as well have provided the tag "scala" or whatever

Comment: And just to clarify. The question itself has no issues. It's just the tag, that might bring up this question to users with 'Eloquent' as preferred tag to his question streaam

Comment: I've made an answer, and touched on the tag issue a hair. If you feel it requires a bit more explanation, please, do let me know.

Comment: @Kendra thanks for your answer. I'm still just learning how StackOverflow really works.

Comment: Not a problem- Once you've got things sort of figured out, the rest tends to make a lot of sense as you go. Best way to learn when you're confused is to ask. :)

Comment: @EricD. Anyone with sufficient reputation can rollback any revision to a post, so long as it is unlocked.

Comment: You are perhaps overlooking that the OP prefers an [eloquent] answer but doesn't master it well enough to post a relevant snippet.  Poor snippets are *very* common, we don't expect the OP to get them right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The owner of a post has a lot of control over the edits made to their posts. Regardless of their reputation, they can single-handedly approve or reject any edit suggested to their post, and they can always use the "rollback" link in the edit history to rollback any change.

This is generally not a problem- The OP tends to be given last word on the edits made to their post. However, if a user is actively making their question much worse by rolling back good edits, or by editing to vandalize their post, this is a problem and should (and likely will) be handled by moderators. As with most actions, you're free to try commenting to the user to explain why their actions are inappropriate, and this could sometimes keep from requiring moderator intervention.

In this particular case, this is not going to be worth making too much fuss over- The tag isn't actively harming the post, and the OP appears to feel that it is, indeed, relevant to their question. I'd suggest just shrugging and moving on in this case. In other cases of clearly, wildly unrelated tags, such as the user adding an [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag to this particular question, that might be worth at least mentioning to them in the comments and trying to sort out. I still doubt it'd be worth mod intervention at that point.

Comment: Actually, making the tag less useful also weighs in the balance. While it doesn't hurt most questions when the empty slots are filled with obviously unrelated tags, it hurts those tags quite a lot, especially if they are small.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks for your input- I hadn't thought to consider from the side of the tags, only from the side of the questions.